# Почему интерфейсы упрощают жизнь?

Tags: java, интерфейс

Ранее никогда не писал собственные интерфейсы для "упрощения жизни". Почему? Что в них такого интересного?

В комментариях попросили добавить в вопрос мои знания и область работы. Пишу android приложения и... Все. Об интерфейсах не знаю ничего, только то, что можно класс от интерфейса наследовать и переопределить методы. Но зачем? Смысл интерфейсов?

Спасибо за замечательные ответы!

Comment: [Знакомьтесь](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2014/10/solid.html)

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в вопрос, что вы знаете об интерфейсах (может быть в знаниях пробелы) и какого рода приложения/код вы пишете (может быть они вам и не нужны).

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: класс не наследует методы оь интерфеса, он их реализует

Comment: Проще был бы ответ, что интерфейсами реализуется нужная структура кода, а потом спросить нужна вам она и зачем?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Лично для меня самым наглядным для понимания сущности интерфейсов являются коллекции и все, что с ними связанно. Скорее всего это так, потому что с ними приходилось чаще всего работать.

**Одна из** главных особенностей ООП - избавление от дублирования логики, за счет правильной архитектурной составляющей. Для данного случая (в общем понимании) и были придуманы интерфейсы и абстрактные классы.

Допустим у меня есть сферический в вакууме метод, делающий какую-то работу с коллекцией:

```
/*Здесь может быть любой тип коллекции, который реализует соотв. интерфейс.
Причем я использую интерфейс самого "низкого" уровня, т.к.
он полностью покрывает данный функционал (т.е. проход по элементам в цикле)
Также я могу написать любую свою реализацию для этого интерфейса
*/
public void showCollectionAtConsole(Iterable<?> col){
   col.forEach(object -> System.out.println(object));
}
```

Удобство здесь в том, что только в самой Java довольно много реализаций данного интерфейса, ([подробнее](https://habrahabr.ru/post/237043/)) и я могу использовать данную логику для каждой из них.

Теперь у меня есть другой метод, реализующий какой-то функционал:

```
public boolean removeOrAddMyObject (Collection<MyObject> col, MyObject object){
    //Если удалил объект - true, иначе - false
    boolean isRemove = true;

    if (col!=null){
        if (col.isEmpty() || !col.remove(object)) {
            col.add(object);
            isRemove = false;
        }
    }else throw new IllegalStateException("Коллекция = null");

    return isRemove;
}
```

Здесь мне приходится использовать три метода коллекции: isEmpty(), add(), remove(). Однако все эти методы описаны в интерфейсе Collection и нет нужды в качестве аргумента передавать более "высокий" интерфейс или класс с реализацией.
Как я уже писал выше, данное решение позволит мне с чистой совестью переиспользовать неоднократно данный метод для других реализаций.

Также, как мне кажется, отличным примером использования интерфейсов являются Callback'и:

```
public final class MyClass {

    static class MyObject {
        int id;
        String name;

        public MyObject(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "My Object: id = "+id+", name = "+name;
        }
    }

    //Интерфейс коллбэка
    interface MyCallback<T extends MyObject> {
        void doSome(T myObject);
    }

    
    static void doSomeAwesome(MyObject object, MyCallback<MyObject> callback) {
        System.out.println(object);
        callback.doSome(object);
        System.out.println(object);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyObject myObject = new MyObject(1,"someName");

        MyCallback<MyObject> callback = new MyCallback<MyObject>() {
            @Override
            public void doSome(MyObject myObject) {
                myObject.setId(2);
                myObject.setName("someOtherName");
            }
        };

        doSomeAwesome(myObject,callback);
    }
}
```

Суть сводится к тому, что в интерфейсе коллбэка вы явным образом определяете дженерик (если хотите передавать в метод параметры и/или получать из метода объекты) и описываете контракт. В моем случае это один метод, принимающий на вход аргумент. Теперь, я могу реализовать метод коллбэка на свое усмотрение, и таким образом расширить использование метода `doSomeAwesome()` дополнительной логикой.

Если выполнить код на выходе будет:

> My Object: id = 1, name = someName
>
> My Object: id = 2, name = someOtherName

**UPD:** *Также следует понимать, что есть и другие контексты для использования интерфейсов:*

- контекст множественного наследования (в Java нельзя наследоваться от более 1 класса, но можно имплементировать более 1 интерфейса)
- интерфейс как прослойка между взаимодействующими сущностями. Т.е. есть два модуля в программе которые выполняют разные функции и при этом взаимодействуют друг с другом. В идеальной ситуации оба модуля должны представлять друг для друга "черный ящик" с необходимым минимумом методов, описываемых интерфейсами. Таким образом куда проще избежать сложностей при последующей отладке кода.
- контекст проектирования архитектуры приложения. Как правило, на начальном этапе проектирования архитектуры будущего приложения, очень удобно "прикидывать" взаимодействие между сущностями с помощью интерфейсов. Это как будто черновой вариант, который не требует "заморачиваться" с реализацией, и позволяет относительно безболезненно модифицировать архитектуру на ранних этапах.
- контекст тестирования. Как уже упоминали в одном из ответов, использование интерфейсов позволяет: "использовать Mock-объекты вместо настоящих". Поверьте, в перспективе это очень облегчает жизнь.

Answer (score 17):

Интерфейс предоставляет контракт, который должны выполнять все классы, реализующие этот интерфейс, и является абстракцией, показывающей что объект может делать, но как он этот делает - не важно.

На практике это приводит к следующему:

При использовании интерфейсов появляется возможность заменять один класс, реализующий интерфейс, на другой класс, реализующий этот же интерфейс, без переписывания всего кода. Например, если методу передаётся `Map`:

```
public void handle(Map map) { ... }
```

то не придётся менять описание метода, если потребуется использовать `TreeMap` вместо `HashMap`.
Аналогично если метод возвращает `Map`: он может начать возвращать `TreeMap` вместо `HashMap`, и трагедии библейских масштабов при этом не случится, так как код, работающий с возвращенным этим методом значением, имеет дело с `Map`.
Это увеличивает гибкость кода: проще переключаться с одного источника данных на другой и с одной реализации на другую.
Также это полезно при тестировании, так как позволяет использовать [Mock-объекты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82) вместо настоящих.

---

Если нужно одинаково обрабатывать коллекции элементов (например, `ArrayList` и `Set`, возвращаемый методом `keySet()` у `HashMap`), то достаточно описать метод так:

```
public <T> void handle(Collection<T> elements) { ... }
```

Использование generics-типа здесь для большей реалистичности. Без использования интерфейса пришлось создавать два метода:

```
public <T> void handle(ArrayList<T> elements) { ... }

public <T> void handle(Set<T> elements) { ... }
```

И либо дублировать код, либо, например, во втором методе создавать `ArrayList`, добавлять в него все элементы из `Set` и вызывать первый метод.

---

Также использование интерфейсов позволяет объединить разные объекты, реализующий один и тот же интерфейс, в один список и одинаково их обрабатывать:

```
public interface Animal
{
    public void feed();
}

public class Dog implements Animal
{
    public void feed() { ... }
}

public class Cat implements Animal
{
    public void feed() { ... }
}

List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
animals.add(new Cat());
animals.add(new Dog());
for (Animal animal : animals)
{
    animal.feed();
}
```

Без использования интерфейса пришлось бы городить "if-else" (или "switch-case") с отдельной реализацией логики для каждого типа животных.

Comment: Добавлю свои пять копеек, интерфейсы сильно упрощают жизнь при тестировании. Позволяют замокать зависимые компоненты на определенное поведение.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov да, я хотел про тесты упомянуть в первом пункте, но потом не стал, ограничившись более общими словами. Думаете, стоит это явно указать?

Comment: думаю все таки стоит дописать, т.к. это дейстительно полезное свойство применения интерфейсов

Comment: @Regent >>Интерфейс предоставляет контракт<< в этих словах прямо чувствуется Rust ))

Answer (score 4):

Потому что интерфейс - это абстракция, которая говорит о том, что делать, а не как делать.  "упрощение жизни" заключается в том, что интерфейс задает единообразное ожидаемое поведение, и где бы вы его не встретили (если конечно программист не наплевал на контракт интерфейса). Вообще, чтобы понять, что я тут написал, вам бы почитать книги по ООП.

Comment: Например, смотрите. У меня есть класс для адаптера списка `RecyclerView`. И отдельный класс `Activity`. В адаптере я хочу поставить слушатель на кнопку. Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы этот слушатель работал в классе `Activity`? Здесь "облегчит жизнь" интерфейс?

Comment: @СергейГрушин То, о чем вы говорите здесь не совсем то, о чем вы спрашиваете в вопросе. Для решения проблемы из комментария вам нужно спрашивать про колбэки (интерфейсы обратного вызова) - это не то же, что в вопросе, точнее вопрос только про часть механизма - конракта на возвращаемое значение.

Comment: Ага.. Я просто не очень понял суть интерфейса. А что можно почитать на эту тему, кэлбеков

Answer (score 2):

Интерфейсы и в правду упрощают жизнь .Допустим в android для навигации `gps Google api`  использую интерфейс, для слушателя используют интерфейс (Интерфейсы используются почти везде даже в потоках )А начиная с Java-8 интерфейсы реализуют и тело, так что можно уже писать не только условие но и тело интерфейса .Но дело каждого  использовать их или нет .Не всегда программист обязан реализовывать свои интерфейсы.Правила "написание хорошего кода"  гласит:сперва составь интерфейсы абстракцию  потом реализуй))

Comment: Вы описали что есть, но забыли написать, *почему же интерфейсы **упрощают** жизнь*?

Comment: тем что не пишешь свои)экономия времени и размера кода

Comment: Какой-то странный ответ. "автомобили упрощают жизнь, потому что не надо делать свои" .. а вопрос то наверно в том, зачем они вообще нужны