# Что означает класс реализует интерфейс?

Tags: java, интерфейс

Встретил это в книге по Java Яков Файн "Программирование на Java...". Вот цитата из книги:

> Должно быть вам интересно, зачем беспокоиться о создании интерфейсов без текста программы? Причина в том, что интерфейс, сделанный однажды, может использоваться во многих других классах. Например, когда другие классы(или сама виртуальная машина JVM) видят, что класс `MyDrawingPad` реализует интерфейс `MouseMotionListener`, они знают, что в этом классе точно есть методы `mouseDragged()` и `mouseMoved()`.

Пожалуйста, объясните то, что написано в цитате из книги.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616119/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объявление интерфейса:

```
public interface IMyInterface {
    public void Barabum() ;
}
```

Пример реализации интерфейса классом MyClass:

```
public class MyClass implements IMyInterface {

    // Реализация интерфейса
    @Override
    public void Barabum(){
        System.out.println("Hi!") ;
    } 

    // Любые другие методы
    public void OtherMethod1(){
        System.out.println("Method1!") ;
    } 

//.................................

    public void OtherMethodN(String s){
        System.out.println("MethodN") ;
    } 
}
```

Здесь запись "implements IMyInterface" говорит о том, что в классе MyClass обязан присутствовать метод Barabum, притом не важно какой именно код этот метод содержит.

Answer (score 3):

Интерфейс это чисто абстрактный класс с виртуальными методами, реализация которых описана в наследуемых от него классах. "Класс реализует интерфейс" означает что он наследует класс-интерфейс и содержит реализацию его виртуальных методов. Т. е. один и тот же метод объявленный в интерфейсе, будучи вызванным из разных классов которые от него унаследованы, будет выполнять разные действия, в зависимости от того как он реализован в конкретном классе-наследнике. А что в книге об этом ничего больше не написано?)

Comment: Реализация метода может быть внутри интерфейса начиная с Java 8

Answer (score 2):

Интерфейс - это грубо говоря лишь название функций, без реализации.

Возьмём, напрмер, человека. Каждый человек умеет ходить, но он может это делать по разному.

Т.е. у человека есть интерфейс "ходить", но как именно будет ходить тот или иной человек зависит от реализации данного интерфейса классом.

Из цитаты мы видим, что класс MyDrawingPad описывает(реализует) интерфейс MouseMotionListener, тк. в интерфейсе есть два метода mouseDragged() и mouseMoved(), значит класс должен описать реализацию данных функций.

Не привожу вам примеры кода, в книге которую вы читаете листинги присутствуют.

Comment: Не функций, а методов. Да и как же дефолтные методы в Java8?